# Get help for a package

Tags: package, documentation

Is there a way to get a quick help for a certain package? Something similar you get when you click package description in `Paradox`. I think it would be interesting a sort of *doc package* which get the list of your installed packages and fetch the `Readme`file of the related Github pages. For example if you get the description of package, say `Helm`, using the `describe-package` command you get a very brief description:

```
helm is an installed package.

 Status: Installed in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/helm-20160824.745/' (unsigned).
Archive: n/a
Version: 20160824.745
Requires: emacs-24.3, async-1.9, popup-0.5.3, helm-core-2.0
Summary: Helm is an Emacs incremental and narrowing framework
Homepage: https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/
Other versions: 20160824.745 (melpa), 2.0 (melpa-stable).
```

Instead it could be really useful to fetch the [Readme](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emacs-helm/helm/master/README.md) and convert to an org file in order have a quick look for the most important commands.

Comment: There isn't one universally accepted way of documenting a package.  Instead there's info manuals, external documentation, bundled documentation, READMEs, commentary inside the file, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The command you are looking for is `describe-package`?

Comment: This command is mentioned in the question, along with an example of its output.

Comment: @phils Indeed, but it was not at the time this "answer" was posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the interactive commands, there is always `C-h b`, which will tell you all of the active keybindings available for current major and minor modes. Search for the mode you are looking for with`C-s`. Documentation for each function is linked to as well.

I use this for exploring features of a mode, as most of the time the function names are self-explanatory, or it gives me more information to web search or use `apropos`to find additional pieces of documentation.